# Compare php array to javascript array same data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Scenario: I need to compare a database cell on the page load (php) against itself in an interval loop every x amount of minutes for changes.

My Initial load data looks like this:

```
var olddata = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data1); ?>) + "~|~" +
    JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data2); ?>) + "~|~" + 
    JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data3); ?>);
```

So on page load, I save the cells into a javascript variable with a "~|~" delimiter, where $data1, $data2, and $data3 are 3 different cells in the database (arrays of data).

And my interval loop data (ajax call) looks like this:

```
// PHP on the AJAX page
echo json_encode($data1)."~|~".json_encode($data2). "~|~".json_encode($data3);

// AJAX code that gets called every x Intervals
$.get("ajaxpage.php", function(data) {
    if (data == olddata) {
         console.log("Good!");
    }
});
```

When I compare `olddata` against `data` they look almost identical except... data that has a `/` in it will look like `\/` in the `data variable and not in the`olddata` variable.

Example:

```
"10":["10"],"11":["11 5\/25"] // data = return from the AJAX call
"10":["10"],"11":["11 5/25"] // olddata = what was originally echoed on page load.
```

How can I compare the two so that they will match perfectly? So that what I echo from the database and json_encode, will line up with what I get from the exact same thing echoed on a page and jason encoded from the json function return.

Note: If I remove the JSON.stringify then it will return [object Object]

Comment: The comparison is useless, my opinion, just take the data and display it...
Also why don't you store olddata as an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a very bad practice. Just use AJAX to get this:

```
var olddata = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data1); ?>) + "~|~" +
JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data2); ?>) + "~|~" + 
JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data3); ?>);
```

And store "olddata" in a JavaScript Global var, then compare the old data with the new data returned by `$.get`. This isn't the solution for your bug, but it's a better way to do what you're doing.

**To fix the bug** just declare the type of the return value in the your `$.get` function, like that:

```
$.get("ajaxpage.php", function(data) {
    if (data == olddata) {
         console.log("Good!");
    }
}, 'text');
```

For more information about the return type, look the jQuery Documentation: [jQuery $.get Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Ahhh Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of grabbing both variables from an AJAX call instead of just the one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to:

```
var olddata = '<?php echo json_encode($data1, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>~|~<?php echo json_encode($data2, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>~|~<?php echo json_encode($data3, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>';
```

And the backend to:

```
echo json_encode($data1, JSON_HEX_APOS)."~|~".json_encode($data2, JSON_HEX_APOS). "~|~".json_encode($data3, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

Now you're simply comparing two strings.

Comment: I just this and I am getting the same issue, it is still adding the back slashes in front of the forward slashes and it is also encoding the single quotes and other characters